# How to use multiple group by with inner join in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables one is **orders** and second is **order_product** in which i have to find our total number of orders and total number of product in corresponding to buyer id.I have find out the total number of product correctly but i was unable
to find out the total number of orders.Below is my table structure.

**orders:**

```
........................
order_id   or_buyer_id
.......................
  1           21
```

**order_product**

```
.................................
op_id  op_order_id  op_buyer_id
.................................
  1       1          21
  2       1          21
```

**I want this output** for this i have applied below query but it returns
right value of product and wrong value of orders.

```
..................................
 or_buyer_id    orders    product
.................................
    21            1        2
```

But i am getting this from below query

```
...............................
or_buyer_id  orders  product
...............................
   21         2       2
```

my query:

```
SELECT o.`or_buyer_id`, count(o.`or_buyer_id`) as orders, count(op.op_buyer_id) as product FROM `orders` as o inner JOIN order_product as op on op.op_order_id=o.order_id and o.or_buyer_id = op.op_buyer_id group by o.`or_buyer_id`
```

Comment: which column has total products? The information you posted seems incomplete. Also post your expected output.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the following link explains how to get this done:

MySQL INNER JOIN with GROUP BY clause

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx

```
SELECT 
    T1.orderNumber,
    status,
    SUM(quantityOrdered * priceEach) total
FROM
    orders AS T1
        INNER JOIN
    orderdetails AS T2 ON T1.orderNumber = T2.orderNumber
GROUP BY orderNumber;
```

so the answer to your query would look like this:

```
SELECT 
    ord.or_buyer_id,
    count(DISTINCT ord.or_buyer_id) as orders,
    count(op.op_id) as product 
FROM 
    orders as ord
inner JOIN 
    order_product as op  
ON 
    op.op_order_id=ord.order_id 
and 
    ord.or_buyer_id = op.op_buyer_id
group by 
    ord.or_buyer_id
```

Comment: it is running fine in the before condition but fails when one entry in orders table and two entries in product tables.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to select `or_buyer_id` and group by it, and add extra join condition to match `or_buyer_id` between the two tables:

```
SELECT o.`or_buyer_id`,
  count(DISTINCT o.`or_buyer_id`) as orders,
  count(op.op_id) as product 
FROM `orders` as o
inner JOIN order_product as op  on op.op_order_id=o.order_id 
                               and o.or_buyer_id = op.op_buyer_id
group by o.`or_buyer_id`;
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7b902/3)

```
| or_buyer_id | orders | product |
|-------------|--------|---------|
|          21 |      1 |       2 |
```

Comment: no this query fails in one condition suppose i have only one entry in orders

Comment: @varunjoshi - Please edit your question with extra sample data that will make the query failed. The query gives you the exact results that you are looking for, you can check the demo and try it yourself.

Comment: it is running fine in the before condition but fails when one entry in orders table and two entries in product tables.

Comment: @varunjoshi I edited my answer, please try the updated query and check the demo again.

Comment: @varunjoshi You just need `count(distinct`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162073/discussion-between-varun-joshi-and-braddock-br).